Playwright git workflow error on execution failed BEWARE: your OS is not officially supported by Playwright; installing
Getting this error:
BEWARE: your OS is not officially supported by Playwright; installing dependencies for ubuntu20.04-x64 as a fallback.
Installing dependencies...
Switching to root user to install dependencies...

Workflow code:
runs-on: self-hosted
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v4
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
    with:
      node-version: 18
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      if [ -e yarn.lock ]; then
      yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      elif [ -e package-lock.json ]; then
      npm install
      else
      npm i
      fi
  - name: Install Playwright Browsers
    run: npx playwright install --with-deps
  - name: Run Playwright tests

The workflow should have executed successfully post installation. Installation of browsers failed.

Have you tried with an OS that is supported? Also note npm i and npm install are the same thing.
